# Python - get the path of a given item from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, path

I have a function that converts a file path into a dictionary:

```
def get_directory_structure(rootdir):
    """
    Creates a nested dictionary that represents the folder structure of rootdir
    """
    dir = {}
    rootdir = rootdir.rstrip(os.sep)
    start = rootdir.rfind(os.sep) + 1
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
        folders = path[start:].split(os.sep)
        subdir = dict.fromkeys(files)
        parent = reduce(dict.get, folders[:-1], dir)
        parent[folders[-1]] = subdir
    return dir
```

Example output for [image: this]:

```
path_dict = {'Desktop': {
               'sensup.sh': None, 
               'sensdown.sh': None, 
               '1': {
                  '2': {
                     '3': {
                        '4': {}}}}}}
```

I need to create a function that when given the name of a file or folder from this directory, it outputs its path. For example `get_directory('3', path_dict)` would output `Desktop/1/2/3`.

Here's what I tried:

```
def get_path_from_dict(base_path, base_name, ob, path=''):
        if ob and base_name in list(ob.keys()):
            path = f"{base_path}{path}/{base_name}"
            print(path)
            return path
        elif not ob:
            pass
        else:
            for key, value in sorted(ob.items()):
                get_path_from_dict(base_path, base_name, value, f'{path}/{key}')
```

Where `base_path` is the beginning of the full path, so `home/user` in this case, `base_name` is the file name to be searched for, and `ob` is the path dictionary. When I print the final path, it comes out correctly, but when I print the return value it comes out as `None` and I'm not sure why.

Output of `print(get_path_from_dict('/home/user', "3", path_dict))`:

```
/home/user/Desktop/1/2/3 ((from print))
None                     ((from return value))
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you get `None` is because you forgot to put the `return` keyword in your code when your are calling this function recursively.

You are doing this recursively so in the last line of your code you have to add `return` keyword at the beginning of the line:
(this is your code but with a minor change to fix it)

```
def get_path_from_dict(base_path, base_name, ob, path=''):
    # other codes
    # other codes

    else:
        for key, value in sorted(ob.items()):
            ###################################
            # notice the return keyword below #
            ###################################
            return get_path_from_dict(base_path, base_name, value, f'{path}/{key}')
```

I executed this code with your input and it works fine. If you have any question ask me my friend.

Comment: I realized this just now and was about to come and update the post when I saw this. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @AdibBaji Your welcome my friend. I'm glad that your problem is solved. If this answer is good please accept it. Or if you have any questions feel free to ask me. I'd be happy to help you.

Comment: I am having a new issue. I have made the directory a little more complex. [This](https://pastebin.com/raw/xY7wtjVK) is the new `path_dict`.  However, many of the paths are still getting [returned as None](https://pastebin.com/raw/DefNdxmf). I know this is because I have the `pass` line, but the code should never reach that line if I'm only searching for files that I know exist in the dictionary.